# Javascript, that will reload page and then click on something

Tags: javascript

I want to create some javascript that will automatically click on button on my page, then wait 2 hours, and then reload page and do it again.

But if I use a `setTimeout` for 7210000 ms (*two hours in ms*) it doesn't work, and I don't know why. What's going on, how can I make this work?

```js
setTimeout(function autoClick() {
  const list = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  list[2].click()
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload()
}, 7210000);
```

Comment: Have the initial code store the current time. Then, use `setInterval()` (not `.setTimeout()`) to run every 60 minutes (thus cutting down your milliseconds number in half) and when that callback function runs, see if the current time is 2 hours later than the original time. If so, cancel the timer and run the `click` code.

Comment: @FaizanKhan Usually we'd want all the code, but you really need the HTML here? I don't think so.

Comment: Does your code work if you reduce the timeout value to something like 300 milliseconds? 7,210,000 milliseconds is well within [the 2,147,483,647 millisecond maximum delay value for most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Maximum_delay_value)

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works with lower numbers, but with more that 1 hour timer, it just doesnt call that reload page code.. I will do it like the Scott said, I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the start time (the time at page loaded) then check every amount of time if 2 hours have passed or not

```js
    var timeStart = new Date();
    var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var timeNow = new Date();
        var difference = timeNow - timeStart;
        difference = difference / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        console.log(difference);
        if(difference >= 2){
           window.location.reload()
        }
    },1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, this one will work for sure.. I'm new in the javascripting, so I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question.

Comment: why not run the function every two hours instead of checking every second ? performance wise this is heavy

Comment: @ZohirSalak The problem is it doesn't work when he runs it every two hours, 1 second is just for the example and to see the result in the snippet run in the answer, he can change it to 1 minute or something :)

Comment: I will do the rest  by my self, I just needed starting point. :)

Comment: How do you get this to continue the loop after the reload? On my end, after the first reload, the loop is terminated.

Comment: The idea is that the loop isn't continued, but it do the same thing everytime the page loads.

Comment: When the page loads, you get the start time of loading then calculate how much time has passed since loading the page.
If 2 hours have passed you reload again, and so on.

If you want to save the time on which the page loaded the first time, you can use `localStorage`